# Logstash with inluxdb

Tags: logstash, influxdb

Please help to understand. I installed on my host logstash and influxdb. Create database with user on influxdb and change output parameter to it. Also installed logstash-output-influxdb.
There is example :

```
output {
    http {
            url => "http://localhost:8086/db/logstash/series?u=root&p=root"
            format => "message"
            content_type => "application/json"
            http_method => "post"
            message => "%{message}"
            verify_ssl => false
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

But nothing.  How investigate it or what step i missed. Help please. If someone working with this give some exaples of configs.

Comment: What version of InfluxDB are you using? The syntax in the example above would only work with InfluxDB versions 0.8 or prior.

Comment: @beckettsean  
Hello, thank you for the response. I using 0.9.6 version of influxdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in your example is valid only for the API in InfluxDB 0.8 or earlier. Since you are using 0.9.6, that endpoint does not exist. In addition, the JSON write protocol is deprecated in 0.9.x, although still functional.

It sounds as though all the logstash docs reference InfluxDB 0.8 API and endpoints. I don't think you can trust much of it to be precise. Perhaps ask the maintainers to update the examples for InfluxDB 0.9+